# proof of the convergence of a series of Fourier coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $a \in (0,1/2]$ and define $ f:\mathbb T\rightarrow \mathbb R $ by 
$$
f(x)
= \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $x$ is between $-a$ and $a$} \\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I figured out all the Fourier coefficients of $f$, but the question asks me to show the sum of all these Fourier coefficients converges as an infinite series to $f(0)$.
Could someone help me with this problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: What kind of theorems do you know that guarantee convergence of Fourier series?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dini's test in this case, since the function is pretty simple. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DinisTest.html)

Comment: From what I know, Dini's test proves uniform convergence of a monotone sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a continuous function on a compact set. But now the problem is about the convergence of a numerical series. So could you elaborate on what you mean by using Dini's test to show the sum of all the Fourier coefficients converges to f(0)?